# Oracle existsNode payload search

Tags: sql, oracle

Any help would be appreciated with the below as I cannot figure out what’s wrong , I’m search CLOBS in my table using the existNode function and I am able to successfully search for specific values but what I’m looking to do is check if an optional  is present in the payload

Table Name : EventPaylods

```
<A>
       <B>
             <C>
                    <C_a> 123</C_a>
                     <C_b>456</C_b>
             </C>
     </B>
</A>
```

So given the “payload “ above I am able to “find” this payload in my table using the following query

```
Select * 
From EventPayload
Where existsNode ( PAYLOAD, ‘/*:A/*:B/*:C/*C_a[.=“123”]’)>=1
```

But what I’m trying to do is find the payload without knowing the value of   , I’ve done some research and I should be able to simply find it by using the below but for some reason it just doesn’t work , any help would be appreciated

```
Select * 
From EventPayload
Where existsNode ( PAYLOAD, ‘/*:A/*:B/*:C/*C_a’)>=1
```

Answer (score 0):

In XQuery, the part before the `:` is for the namespace and after is the tag name so `*:A` is any namespace and a tag named `A`. You don't appear to be using namespaces so your query can simply written as:

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE eventpayload ( payload CLOB );

INSERT INTO eventpayload ( payload )
VALUES ( '<A><B><C><C_a>123</C_a><C_b>456</C_b></C></B></A>' );
```

**Query**:

```sql
Select * 
From EventPayload
Where existsNode ( XMLTYPE( PAYLOAD ), '/A/B/C/C_a[text()="123"]') = 1;
```

and without the `text()` filter:

```sql
Select * 
From EventPayload
Where existsNode ( XMLTYPE( PAYLOAD ), '/A/B/C/C_a') = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=10dc9b0148f7b2e89d433a4799681da5)